# Using a wildcard in a variable for Get-ChildItem filter

Tags: powershell

Below is the code

```
$now = [System.DateTime]::Now

$filter = $now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + "_*_S1.txt"
Write-Host $filter

Get-ChildItem -filter $filter | % {Write-Host $_}# Select-Object -OutVariable $files

Write-Host $files.GetType()
```

I can take the output of the 'Write-Host $filter' statement and paste it into PowerShell and get the results I expect, so I know the filter is correct.  Is it because I'm using a variable in the get-childitem call?  How would one go about doing this.

Comment: I meant descriptive in showing what you are asking from us instead of stating you don't understand something :P Remember the question title is what comes up on the frontpage and is what makes people decide whether they want to have a look at your question or not.

Comment: $files isn't getting populated by anything in your code.

Comment: I've tried to edit the title to make it a little more relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing `-OutVariable`. It's expecting the name of the variable *without* the `$`. So you should be using `Select-Object -OutVariable files`.

But your code is very un-PowerShell-y. Using the pipeline & `Select-Object` is completely unnecessary here. Try this instead.

```
$filter = $(get-date -f "MM_dd_yyyy") + "_*_S1.txt";
$files = Get-ChildItem -filter $filter;
```